# Reduce list of list to dictionary with sublist size as keys and number of occurances as value

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, reduce

I have a list of lists and I want to count the number of times a sublist with a specific size occurs.

eg. for list `[[1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]]` I expect to get `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1}`

I've tried `reduce` function but I have syntax error on `+= 1` and have no idea what is wrong.

```
list_of_list = [[1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
result = functools.reduce(lambda dict,list: dict[len(list)] += 1, list_of_list, defaultdict(lambda: 0, {}))
```

Comment: The reason this is not working is because you are assigning values within lambda. In python, assignment statements cannot be used in lambda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use `reduce` in such a complicated way when you can use `collections.Counter()` with `map()` function in a more Pythonic way:

```
>>> A = [[1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> Counter(map(len,A))
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1})
```

Note that using `map` will perform slightly better than a generator expression because by passing a generator expression to `Counter()` python will get the values from generator function by itself, since using built-in function `map` has more performance in terms of execution time<sup>1</sup>.

```
~$ python -m timeit --setup "A = [[1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]];from collections import Counter" "Counter(map(len,A))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.7 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit --setup "A = [[1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]];from collections import Counter" "Counter(len(x) for x in A)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.73 usec per loop
```

From [PEP 0289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

> The semantics of a generator expression are equivalent to creating an anonymous generator function and calling it. For example:
>
> ```
> g = (x**2 for x in range(10))
> print g.next()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def __gen(exp):
>     for x in exp:
>         yield x**2
> g = __gen(iter(range(10)))
> print g.next()
> ```

---

<sub>Note that since *generator expressions* are better in terms of memory use, if you are dealing with large data you'd better use *generator expression* instead of *map* function.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as well:

```
list_of_list = [[1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
c = Counter(len(i) for i in list_of_list)
```

Output:

```
Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1})
```

Comment: Nitpicky: you don't need the intermediate list in the `Counter` constructor, it can accept a generator expression: `c = Counter(len(i) for i in list_of_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` is an inferior tool for this job.

Look at a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) instead.  It's a dict subclass, so you should be able to use it however you were planning to use the dict.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> Counter(len(x) for x in L)
Counter({1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1})
```